# How to pass Python objects (that are not JSON serializable) from one (AWS) lambda function to another?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

If you try to send an object that's not JSON serializable (anything other than list, dictionary, integer, etc.), you get the following error message:

```
"errorMessage": "Object of type set is not JSON serializable"
```

Even if you send a `tuple`, it gets converted into a `list` when it's passed to the second lambda.

So, what are the workarounds, if you want to preserve the object?

Answer (score 5):

#### One option:

- Create an encoded string representation of the object and pass it, using a function like this:

  ```
  def native_object_encoded(x):
      x = pickle.dumps(x)
      x = zlib.compress(x)
      x = base64.b64encode(x).decode()
      return x
  ```
- In the second lambda function, perform the same steps in reverse to get back the original object:

  ```
  def native_object_decoded(s):
      s = base64.b64decode(s)
      s = zlib.decompress(s)
      s = pickle.loads(s)
      return s
  ```

#### Usage:

```
# lambda 1 (the caller)
a = {66, 99, 35} # set: not serializable
payload = {
    'a': native_object_encoded(a),
}
response = client.invoke(
...
)

# lambda 2 (the one being invoked)
a = native_object_decoded(event['a'])
```

**Notes**:

- If the object is of custom type, that type must be defined in the second lambda function too.
- If the object is part of some other library (standard or third-party), that library should be imported in the second lambda function.
- The compression step is optional.